# Mongo vs Mongoid - why can 1 connect and the other not?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a rails-app which uses both mongoid and mongo. I use mongoid for my own models, and I use mongo because I have ruote with a ruote-mon storage.

In production however; I get

```
Mongo::ConnectionFailure: Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017
```

when I try to connect to the ruote storage. Even when I just do `Mongo::MongoClient.new`

Steps I have taken so far to try to resolve this:

1. I have made my mongodb an explicit master by setting `master = true` in `/etc/mongod.conf`
2. There are no $ENV variables set that could intervene with `Mongo::MongoClient.new` (double checked)
3. I have tried to connect using `Mongo::MongoClient.new(:slave_ok => true)` - same error
4. I have restarted my mongo database several times (w/o success).
5. I have checked my firewall settings and I can connect to localhost:27017 with telnet (as said, the mongoid documents can be fetched and stored w/o issue)

I am out of my wits... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please look at: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-525

Should be fixed by the 1.8.2 mongo gem.

Comment: Not the entire/final answer, but many thanks for the pointers in that nice ticket.

Comment: There is not enough info in your report to give you a final answer ;-) You are especially not detailing the differences between the dev and the prod environment and you are not giving any detail about the versions (gem / mongod / ruby / oses) you use. Giving these pieces of information immediately saves time (your time, the time of the people who help).

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happened is because we were sending queries with meta operators ($query, $orderby, etc...) for the ismaster command during a connect. This command's output is used to determine whether you are connected to a primary or not and would fail because very old versions of mongodb don't support the use of meta operators.

This fix will be in version 1.8.2 of the gem but I strongly encourage anyone who is still running pre-1.8 versions of mongodb to upgrade. 2.0 is the current legacy release as of the time of this post and even 1.8 is no longer widely supported.

As jmettraux mentioned you can find more details about this on the MongoDB project Jira under [Ruby-525](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-525)